# Executing JavaScript instructions after loading HTML file in a WebView

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview, handler

I realized an Android program that loads a HTML file into a WebView, the HTML file loads Leaflet.js that shows different styles of maps based on the provider you gave it.

I load the page in the OnCreate() method with this instruction:

```
myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/test.html");
```

After that, I need to take the list of different maps from a Handler (with class name JavascriptInterface.java) that I added to the WebView like this:

```
myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(this, myWebView), "MyHandler");
```

The final code needs to look like this:

```
myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/test.html");
myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:window.MyHandler.getMaps()");
```

The problem is that the first loadUrl() isn't fast enough, so the second loadUrl goes before the map is initialized, causing a lot of problems.

The temporary, and also horrible, solution that I found is to hold the second loadUrl for 1 second before executing it, like this:

```
myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/test.html");

Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // Actions to do after 1 second
        myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:window.MyHandler.getMaps()");
    }
}, 1000);
```

There is a better way of executing an instruction after another one? I already tried using an ASyncTask, but there is the possibility that I didn't implemented it well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please call myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:window.MyHandler.getMaps()"); inside Webview onPageFinished event.

```
     myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
               Log.d("WebView", "onPageStarted " + url);
            }
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
               myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:window.MyHandler.getMaps()");
            }
        });
     myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/test.html");
```